# ThreeJS - render mesh with curved surface as black and white drawing

Tags: three.js

I want to render a mesh with curved surfaces like in this image:

[image: desired result]

Using the EdgesHelper I got this

[image]

or, increasing the number of faces and the thresholdAngle of the EdgeHelper:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
Following this suggestions [Three.js outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561360/three-js-outlines)

I used the EdgeHelper plus:

```
var outline_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color : 0x000000, side: THREE.BackSide});
var outline = new THREE.Mesh(mesh.geometry, outline_mat);
outline.scale.multiplyScalar(1.02);
scene.add(outline);
```

result:
[image]